# Group by day, time and id in one LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Example` class elements:

```
public class Example
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to group it using **ONE** `LINQ` to make the following hierarchy:

```
public class GroupedByDay
{
   public List<GroupedByTime> TimeGroup { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedByTime
{
   public List<GroupedById> IdGroup { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedById
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, the result is a list of type `List<GroupedByDay>` with the `Examples` grouped by days, hours (timespans?) within these days and finally by ids.

Can anyone help me with it?

**[edit]**
This is what I tried to group by Ids, but I think I should start from the other side maybe?

```
var result =
   examples
      .GroupBy(e => e.Id, e => new GroupedById
         {
            Name = e.Name
         });
```

Comment: What Linq code did you try?

Comment: Check my edits plz, I added some missing things. The problem is I have some daily tasks. I want to group these task by days (because I want to show them for a whole week, day after day). Now inside each day I want to group it by same hours. Some tasks can be the same, I don't want to show them duplicated.

Comment: And as always... No help, just -1...

Comment: Are the classes `GroupedByDay`, `GroupedByTime` and `GroupedById` really necessary? Can't you just have a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Example>>`?

Comment: Hmm, but if I have `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Example>>` then how to group by days and inside days by hours at the same time? Maybe I'm wrong with something;S

Comment: @Nickon they'll all be at separated, but at the same grouping level. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to group for displaying purposes, you don't need the classes `GroupedByDay`, `GroupedByTime` and `GroupedById`

Considering `examples` is an `IEnumerable<Example>`

```
var groupedExamples = from example in examples 
        group example by new { 
                              example.SomeDate.Date, //Day
                              example.SomeDate.Hour, // Hour
                              example.Id // Id
        } into g
        select g;
```

Then you'll have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,Example>>` with the desired grouping:

```
foreach(var g in groupedExample){
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Day {0} at hour {1} with id {2}", g.Key.Date, g.Key.Hour, g.Key.Id));

    foreach(var example in g)
        Console.WriteLine(" - " + example.Name);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I Usually write these code

```
 public static DateTime GetDateByWeekDay(DateTime startDate, int week, Int32 day)
       {

           int Year = Getyear(startDate);
           DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(Year, 1, 1);
           int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Monday - jan1.DayOfWeek;

           DateTime firstMonday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
           var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
           int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstMonday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

           var weekNum = week;
           if (firstWeek <= 1)
           {
               weekNum -= 1;}
           var result = firstMonday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);
           return result.AddDays(day);


       }
```

Comment: What it has to do with OP's question?